# Draw generalized k-ellipse using "the locus of points so that sum of the distances to the foci is constant" deffinition

Tags: plotting, geometry

My goal is to draw a family (for different distances) of *3-ellipse*  for equilateral set of foci.

*3-ellipse* definition is:

> "the locus of points so that sum of the distances to the three foci is constant"

Eventually I want to generalize this to **k-ellipse**.

Thanks for your help I am bloked.

Comment: You know that a regular 2D ellipse is the locus of points so that sum of the distances to the foci is constant. Can you solve this problem in 2D? If so, you would be in a better position to solve it in 3D (or higher).

Comment: Sorry for my english and thanks for the help!

Comment: Please consider registering your account

Answer (score 5):

```
a = 10;
r = RandomInteger[{0, a}, {3, 2}];
ContourPlot[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ r],
 Evaluate[{x, # - a, # + a} &@Mean[r[[All, 1]]]],
 Evaluate[{y, # - a, # + a} &@Mean[r[[All, 2]]]],
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@r}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Dynamically add foci:

```
a = 10;
r = RandomInteger[{0, a}, {3, 2}];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ u],
  Evaluate[{x, # - a, # + a} &@Mean[r[[All, 1]]]],
  Evaluate[{y, # - a, # + a} &@Mean[r[[All, 2]]]],
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@u}],
 {{u, r}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Answering your comment about drawing the intersection of a **k-ellipse cone** and a Sphere:

```
pol[n_] := Array[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &, n + 1, {0., 2 Pi}] // Chop
r = Join[#, {z}] & /@ (z Most@pol[3]);
p = ContourPlot3D[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ r], 
                 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
                 Contours -> {4}, 
                 MeshFunctions -> (EuclideanDistance[{#1, #2, #3}, {0, 0, 1}] &), 
                 Mesh -> {{1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[p, Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Yellow, Specularity[White, 10], 
                   Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, 1]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p1 = ContourPlot3D[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ r], 
                   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
                   Contours -> {4}, 
                   MeshFunctions -> (EuclideanDistance[{#1, #2, #3}, {0, 0, 1}] &), 
                   Mesh -> {{1}}, ContourStyle -> None];
Graphics3D@Cases[p1, GraphicsComplex[__]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Have you any refference to `k-ellipse cone`? What you've shown is what was my understanding of this but is this really it?

Comment: @Kuba I thought it was you who found it. But no, and I'm not very inclined to search for it :)

Comment: ok, so we have to wait for OP's confirmation :)

Answer (score 4):

Basing on belisarius code:

```
pol[n_] := Array[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &, n + 1, {0., 2 Pi}] // Chop

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ Most@pol[n]]
             , {x, -1.3, 1.3}, {y, -1.3, 1.3}, 
               Epilog -> {PointSize@.02, White, Point@pol[n]}, Contours -> 15]
 , {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exacly what I need! This is art!
I need now to create a 3-ellipse cone and look the interserction with the sphere, idealy i need the equation of the curve ;)

Comment: +1 I had no idea that the **k-ellipse** was a real name

Comment: @belisarius is it? :p I didn't know till [now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) but at the time of posting I was not aware of it :)

Comment: @rapasite I think you should ask a separate question about this. Also, focus on explaining what do you mean by 3-ellipse cone.

Answer (score 3):

```
F[a_, b_] := Sqrt[(a - b).(a - b)]
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ContourPlot[ Total[F[{x, y}, #] & /@ {a, b, c}] == d, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Disk[a, 0.1], Green, Disk[b, 0.1], Blue, Disk[c, 0.1]}]
     ],
  {{a, {-3, -3}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}}, 
  {{b, {2, 0}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}},
  {{c, {0, 3}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}}, 
  {{d, 10}, 0, 50}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image]